# JaxB convert XML schema

Tags: xml, jaxb, for-xml-path, xmladapter

I have used given in http://jeungun.wordpress.com/2009/09/18/binding-to-dynamically-generated-form-elements-in-spring-mvc/,

i am converting that output to xml using jaxb,
Since the above example returns array list, the output is coming like below,

```
<item>
   <label>key1</label>
   <output>value1</output>
</item>
  <item>
   <label>key2</label>
   <output>value2</output>
</item>
```

but i want an output like below,

```
<item>
     <key1>value1</key1>
     <key2>value2</key2>
</item>
```

How to acheive this using jaxb?

I have used the belowcode:

```
 public class item {
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getOutput() {
        return output;
    }

    public void setOutput(String output) {
        this.output= output;
    }

    private String label;
    private String output;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does the job for me...HurrAAAAAAAAAAAAYYYyYy

http://java.dzone.com/articles/mapping-arbitrary-list-objects